# new type and JSON

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, haskell

Working on Week 2 Homework 1, I tried to define a new type DuBool. The following is the relevant portion of the code, with the more traditional version commented out immediately above each line that uses DuBool.

```
newtype DuBool = DuBool (Bool,Bool)
PlutusTx.unstableMakeIsData ''DuBool
--
--
{-# INLINABLE mkValidator #-}
-- This should validate if and only if the two Booleans in the redeemer are equal!
-- mkValidator :: () -> (Bool, Bool) -> ScriptContext -> Bool
mkValidator :: () -> DuBool -> ScriptContext -> Bool
-- mkValidator _ _ _ = True -- FIX ME!
-- mkValidator _ (a,b) _ = traceIfFalse "Bools no match" $ a == b
mkValidator _ (DuBool d) _
    | a==b = True
    | otherwise = traceIfFalse "Bools no match" $ False
  where (a,b) = d
--
--
data Typed
instance Scripts.ValidatorTypes Typed where
-- Implement the instance!
    type instance DatumType Typed = ()
--    type instance RedeemerType Typed = (Bool,Bool)
    type instance RedeemerType Typed = DuBool
--
--
typedValidator :: Scripts.TypedValidator Typed
-- typedValidator = undefined -- FIX ME!
typedValidator = Scripts.mkTypedValidator @Typed
    $$(PlutusTx.compile [|| mkValidator ||])
    $$(PlutusTx.compile [|| wrap ||])
  where
--    wrap = Scripts.wrapValidator @() @(Bool,Bool)
    wrap = Scripts.wrapValidator @() @DuBool
```

This does compile in the repl error-free, and does compile and run in the playground simulator, but failure occurs with evaluation when the grab validation step occurs in the simulator, with

> ```
> , Slot 2: 00000000-0000-4000-8000-000000000000 {Wallet W7ce8}:
>             Contract instance stopped with error: "WalletError (ValidationError (ScriptFailure (EvaluationError [\"PT1\"] \"CekEvaluationFailure\")))" ]
> ```

I went back and attempted to edit the "type GiftSchema =" section to use DuBool, as follows:

```
type GiftSchema =
            Endpoint "give" Integer
--      .\/ Endpoint "grab" (Bool, Bool)
        .\/ Endpoint "grab" DuBool
```

and then the grab definition...

```
-- grab :: forall w s e. AsContractError e => (Bool, Bool) -> Contract w s e ()
grab :: forall w s e. AsContractError e => DuBool -> Contract w s e ()
```

But now compilation in the repl fails (sorry that the color and alignment here does not match what I see in the repl).

> ```
> Prelude Ledger.Scripts PlutusTx> :l src/Week02/Homework1c_jwb.hs
> [1 of 1] Compiling Week02.Homework1 ( src/Week02/Homework1c_jwb.hs, /Users/jwb/plutus/plutus-pioneer-program/code/week02/dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.10.4.20210212/plutus-pioneer-program-week02-0.1.0.0/build/Week02/Homework1.o )
> src/Week02/Homework1c_jwb.hs:117:13: error:
> • No instance for (aeson-1.5.6.0:Data.Aeson.Types.FromJSON.FromJSON
> DuBool)
> arising from a use of ‘endpoint’
> • In the expression: endpoint @"grab" grab
> In an equation for ‘grab'’: grab' = endpoint @"grab" grab
> In an equation for ‘endpoints’:
> endpoints
> = awaitPromise (give' select grab') >> endpoints
> where
> give' = endpoint @"give" give
> grab' = endpoint @"grab" grab
> |
> 117 |     grab' = endpoint @"grab" grab
> |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> src/Week02/Homework1c_jwb.hs:119:1: error:
> • No instance for (Schema.ToSchema DuBool)
> arising from a use of ‘Playground.Schema.endpointsToSchemas’
> • In the expression:
> Playground.Schema.endpointsToSchemas
> @((./) (Endpoint "give" Integer) (Endpoint "grab" DuBool))
> In an equation for ‘schemas’:
> schemas
> = Playground.Schema.endpointsToSchemas
> @((./) (Endpoint "give" Integer) (Endpoint "grab" DuBool))
> |
> 119 | mkSchemaDefinitions ''GiftSchema
> | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> Failed, no modules loaded.
> Prelude Ledger.Scripts PlutusTx>
> ```

It appears that the entire code as written (including what I am leaving out for brevity) can convert (Bool,Bool) to JSON, but not DuBool. I am wondering if there is a simple change, perhaps to the imports, {-# LANGUAGE ... #-}, instantiation, etc. that would incorporate this functionality?

Clearly this is not needed to "solve" homework 1 of week 2, but I do believe it is a valid programmatic approach that will be useful going forward. And I think I am very close. Thanks in advance!

=============================================================

Kurt Sys provided an extremely helpful partial answer. A few rounds of trial and error in the repl led me to this compiling and working-in-the-simulator solution. I've left a comment trail to help anyone else following along.

> ```
> -- import           Playground.Contract  (printJson, printSchemas, ensureKnownCurrencies, stage)
> import           Playground.Contract  (printJson, printSchemas, ensureKnownCurrencies, stage, Generic, FromJSON, ToJSON, ToSchema)
> --
> -- newtype DuBool = DuBool (Bool,Bool)
> data DuBool = DuBool
>   {
>     b1 :: Bool
>    ,b2 :: Bool
>   } deriving (Generic, FromJSON, ToJSON, ToSchema)
> PlutusTx.unstableMakeIsData ''DuBool
> --
> {-# INLINABLE mkValidator #-}
> -- This should validate if and only if the two Booleans in the redeemer are equal!
> -- mkValidator :: () -> (Bool, Bool) -> ScriptContext -> Bool
> mkValidator :: () -> DuBool -> ScriptContext -> Bool
> -- mkValidator _ _ _ = True -- FIX ME!
> -- mkValidator _ (DuBool (a,b)) _ = traceIfFalse "Bools no match" $ a == b
> -- mkValidator _ (a,b) _ = traceIfFalse "Bools no match" $ a == b
> -- mkValidator _ (DuBool d) _
> mkValidator _ (DuBool a b) _
>     | a==b = True
>     | otherwise = traceIfFalse "Bools no match" $ False
> --  where (a,b) = d
> ```

Now I need to understand the difference between "data" and "newtype".

Comment: I believe this should be broken up into multiple questions given the guidelines in [ask] and [help/dont-ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For homework1, you don't need to define a new type. That's what's done in homework2 :). Now, for defining a new data type (which is what you want):

```
data DuBool = DuBool
  {
    b1 :: bool ,
    b2 :: bool
  }
```

adding some type classes (implementing functions of some type classes) to it:

```
data DuBool = DuBool
  {
    b1 :: bool ,
    b2 :: bool
  } deriving (Generic, FromJSON, ToJSON, ToSchema)
```

I think that should work fine.

Comment: VERY helpful. Thank you. See my edit to the original question. If you can somehow incorporate what I produced into your answer I will consider this "answered" but as it stands yours is incomplete. But still very helpful as it led me to the solution.

Comment: I swear on MyRedeemer that I had not looked at homework 2 until now : D

Comment: @XiTouch the answer should be accepted as it was sufficient to lead you to an answer and Kurt has spent the time and effort to understand your long question(s).  If a better answer is provided in future, it can be voted up higher than the current one.

Comment: A little too brief, would benefit from a little more "why" explanation